# Java/Ubuntu - Print outside of main works on Windows but does nothing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java-8, java-console

I have an **Intellij** project. I compile ('Make') it on **Windows**, and sends it onto a **Ubuntu 14.04** remote server, running **Java 1.8**.

My problem is that the **System.out.println() outside of the `main` method prints nothing**.
I've spent a few hours on this problem, and I can ensure that :

- I know the methods are executed because they raise Warnings :
  `Aug 20, 2016 7:35:36 PM org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument finalize
  WARNING: Warning: You did not close a PDF Document`
- When the execution ends, I **always** get the following output for rates : `[]`
- Printing the methods as I call them & place print lines at the begining of these methods, won't do the stuff.

N.B.
To execute my project, I use : `java MyProject.TestAlgo` , with TestAlgo the main Class.

---

**EDIT :**
I expect the output to be a List such as : `[1.0, 2.3, ..., 5.4]`, but I get `[]`

I don't think the problem is programming problem, because whenever I compile it on my computer which runs **Windows**, I get the prints from outside the `main`.

When I compile the project, and run it on the **Ubuntu remote server**, I don't see any output except the prints from the `main`, and the warnings raised by methods from outside main class.
All methods trying to print and called in the main are declared `static`.

Comment: I can't see where your `ratePDF` is called in your main-method.

Comment: Your `main` still doesn't compile because of syntax problems. It would be great if you show us your _real_ code.

Comment: What does the code abbreviated as `[...]` do? Also, do the print statement in `ratePDF` print anything at all? In short, what is the expected output and what do you get?

Comment: @tkausl problem is that I have also PHP called in the `rateElementsDouble(filePDF, listElements)` method.
@fge I'm editing so my question will be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

I was compiling Java with the 1.8.0.101 JDK version on Windows, and running it with the 1.8.0.91 on Ubuntu, which (I think) must have created version conflicts..

I solved the issue by updating Java JRE so I had same versions of Java onto Windows and Ubuntu.